# InitialiseSecureChannel error during profile package installation on an eUICC

Tags: javacard, globalplatform, e-sim, euiccmanager, lpad

I'm assembling the SGP.22 GetBoundProfilePackage response that starts with the InitialiseSecureChannelRequest for which I'm getting a 02 error code that corresponds to invalidSignature in smdpSign in InitialiseSecureChannelRequest.

To compute signature I have concatenated following components (in this order like defined in SGP.22):

- remoteOpId
- transactionId
- controlRefTemplate
- smdpOtPk
- euiccOtPk

with their ASN.1 form with same tags as I set in InitialiseSecureChannelRequest structure. Then I prepared digital signature using same algorithms like for authenticateServer and authenticateClient signatures and sign it with DPpb key. But eUICC still responds with 02 error code within ISC block.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: For all future developers of esim: the problem in my case lies in double-time tagged one-time public key, and therefore the signature check fails. The correct way to do a signature is to concatenate ASN.1 structure with tags of above params (in that exact order) and then sign it with DPpb private key. In ASN.1 of ISC the smdpSign shall have 40 bytes length and smdpOtPk 41 bytes